# Cannot access youtube api with v3

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

Trying to get all videos from my channel with v3, but to no avail. Im getting error 403: forbidden. I have activated the vs api for my account(wich is the one who owns the channel).

```
$.get(
       "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
           part: 'contentDetails',
           id: 'xxx',
           key: 'xxx'
       },
       function (data) {
           $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
               console.log(item);
               pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
               getVids(pid);
           });
       }
    );
```

i get further then this because of this error. What can be wrong else then not activating the api or having the correct keys?

Answer (score 0):

Im so stupid. Read the documentation again and realised that i own the channel and need to use "forUsername" instead of id.